# Alternating sign for unequal numbers

Tags: power-series

How to model a function which satisfies following condition:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}   
    1  & x \in 3,7,11,\ldots\\
   -1 & x \in 1,5,9,\ldots
\end{cases}
$$

The first result can be generated using $4n+1$ and the second with $4n-1$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Can this be modelled using one function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}   
    1  & x=4n-1\\
   -1 & x =4n+1
\end{cases}
\stackrel{u=x+1}{=} \begin{cases}   
    1  & u=4n\\
   -1 &  u=4n+2
\end{cases}
\stackrel{2u=y}{=} \begin{cases}   
    1  & y=2n\\
   -1 & y =2n+1
\end{cases}=(-1)^y
$$
$$=(-1)^\frac{x+1}{2}.$$

This $f(x)$ can be complex-valued unless you restrict its domain to the $x$ such that $x \equiv 1,3 \mod 4$.

Answer (score 2):

One simple answer could be $$f(x)=-\sin \frac{\pi x}{2}$$
with the bonus of being equal to zero for even values of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \equiv 3 \bmod 4 \\ -1 & x \equiv 1 \bmod 4 \end{cases}$$

is a perfectly good definition of a function of the odd integers. Quite frequently, it is even more useful than alternative ways to write this function.